# Exporting node size from NetworkX to Gephi

Tags: python, networkx, gephi

I have a graph in NetworkX. I have:

`nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=node_sizes, ax=ax0)`

Exporting the file to Gephi:

`nx.write_gexf(G, 'graph.gexf')`

However, the node sizes aren't preserved in the export.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the size with NetworkX will just be ignored by Gephi. So, the best way to achieve this that I found was to set each node's size using an attribute on the `'viz'` attribute.

For example, to make all nodes size `200`:

```
for node in G.nodes():
    G.node[node]['viz'] = {'size': 200}
```